# Deploying JavaFx Application jar

Tags: deployment, webview

I am still learning !!!
I am using IDEA 2020.1 Community, Windows 10, Java 1.8, JavaFx 11.02 ans Gluon SceneBuilder 8.5.0

My application (rar file attached) uses two modules and was working fine, including as an exe file produced by launc4j.

Then to keep learning I added a second Stage with WebView to display a small User Guide as a single html file.
Both the primary stage and the secondary stage use the same Controller, where the help window gets initialized:

```
    // initializing help window
    @FXML
    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        webEngine = helpWebView.getEngine();
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(getClass().getResource("RateCalculatorHelp.html")));
        fpath = file.getPath();
        webEngine.load(fpath);
    }
```

The secondary stage is made available to the Controller by Main.start:

```
        RateOfChangeController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.initHelpStage(anotherStage);
```

The Controller uses the helpStage variable to show or close the Window:

```
    public void initHelpStage(Stage anotherStage) {
        helpStage =  anotherStage;
    }
    public void showUserGuide(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        helpStage.show();
    }
    public void quitApp(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        helpStage.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

It works file when running Main within IDEA. Then I produced a jar file. When running it from inside IDEA everything
works fine except for the help window, it shows up but is empty, the html file does not get loaded !  And the html file is
included in the jar.

Problem in configuring the artifact ?  Some advise or pointers to relevant examples would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following work-around: a method in the Controller will read the html file et return its content as a string:

```
    public String readFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        // borrowed from alvinalexander.com
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { sb.append(line); }
        is.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

and then the initialize() method of the controller becomes:

```
    // initializing help window
    @FXML
    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        webEngine = helpWebView.getEngine();
        String html = readFromFile("RateCalculatorHelp.html");
        webEngine.loadContent(html);
    }
```

And now it works from the jar file run from the IDEA, by double-clicking the jar file in Windows Explorer, or in the form of an exe file produced by launc4j.

I am still interested to hear from anyone who could explain why the first version did not work !